# Calculating the X-mas day using sql-server

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql-server 2012

I got this query to calculate x-mas day,but unable to get the logic:

`select dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,-1,getdate()),-7)`

datediff(yy,-1,getdate()) gives 115

but how does this workto get me `december 25`?

please explain..

Answer (score 2):

In sql server , the start date is always taken as `1900`.

so in `datediff function` :

```
select datediff(yy,-1,getdate()) = 115 --> 1900-1 = 1899 till 2014 = 115
```

`In dateadd function` :

```
select dateadd(yy,115,-7)= Jan 2015 -7 days  = 25-12-2014
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is `-7` in the `dateadd function` which gives you the date with `'25 dec'`

In Sql Server First date for datetime datatype is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000` so `-7` would be `1899-12-25 00:00:00.000`

From there you are adding some `x` years(115) so you will get a date with `2014-12-25 00:00:00.000`

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE #temmp(dates DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #temmp
    VALUES      (0),(1),(2),(3),(-7) 

Select * from #temmp
```

**Result:**

```
dates 
1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
1900-01-02 00:00:00.000
1900-01-03 00:00:00.000
1900-01-04 00:00:00.000
1899-12-25 00:00:00.000
```

Last Row date is `1899-12-25 00:00:00.000`(which is used in your `DateAdd function`) so from there you are adding some `x` years(115) which is going to give you a date with `2014-12-25 00:00:00.000`

Answer (score 0):

DATEDIFF accepts three parameters, first parameter will define on wht you are going to find difference , second and third parameters are startdate and enddate.

In your case , you gave -1 as startdate which is nothing but

```
select cast(-1 as datetime) --1899-12-31 00:00:00.000
select getdate() --2014-12-25 23:22:36.493
```

`select (2014-1899) --115` is your year difference.

On top, there is one more dateadd funtion which accepts three parameters again, wherein second parameter is number and third is date.

You gave -7 which is equivalent to `select cast(-7 as datetime) --1899-12-25 00:00:00.000` 
Note: **-7 days from sqlserver STARTDATE(1900-01-01 00:00:00.000) => 1899-12-25 00:00:00.000**

wherein year part gives you 1899 to which we are adding 115
So `select 1899 + 115` = 2014 which yields as below

**select dateadd(yy,115,'1899-12-25 00:00:00.000') --2014-12-25 00:00:00.000**